# have neovim use both tmux buffers & system clipboard as both registers

Tags: buffer, clipboard, neovim

I'm fairly new to neovim (`nvim`) so forgive my lack of knowledge, many questions are similar to mine, but not quite the same.

#### I would like this:

- by default should cut/copy to a buffer, not system clipboard.
- it's other register (I think its `+`, please correct me if its `*`!) should go to the system clipboard.

I have done some research but nothing (so far) is working for me.

#### Info:

- I use `tmux` so pushing to `tmux` buffers.
- I'm away from home, so currently using `termux` so `termux-clipboard-get/set`

Here is what I thought would work in my case:

```sh
let g:clipboard = {
  \   'name': 'TmuxTermux',
  \   'copy': {
  \      '*': ['tmux', 'load-buffer', '-'],
  \      '+': ['termux-clipboard-set'],
  \    },
  \   'paste': {
  \      '*': ['tmux', 'save-buffer', '-'],
  \      '+': ['termux-clipboard-get'],
  \   },
  \   'cache_enabled': 1,
  \ }
```

Now when I cut/copy, `tmux` buffers share `vim`'s content, PERFECT! (almost...),
I cannot use the `+` buffer to use the system clipboard though, if I press '+' its just moves my cursor down by one line, if I swap the above order (make `termux-clipboard-get/set` the `*` register, instead of `+`), when I press `*` it highlights all instances of the word my cursor is on.

#### From reading, I expected:

- By default, `nvim` use `*` register, this seems to be true as it successfully registers to `tmux` buffers with `dd/yy` and pastes with `p` (or in `tmux` with my bind of `[PREFIX]+[p]`
- If I want to cut/copy/paste to my other register `+` (system clipboard), then I would use `+dd/+yy` and then paste with `+p` (or even `*dd/*yy/*p`) but this isnt working for me.

#### Problem:

As explained above, `+` will move my cursor down one line, when changing it to the `*` register, `*` highlights the current word and any other occurance of it

Apologies to those with more experience, I'm fresh from `emacs` (with a very sore pinky finger!:)

Comment: You are new to Neovim, not to Vim. The two editors implement clipboard integration differently so this question only concerns Neovim. Please edit your question so that it reflects reality.

Comment: I was unaware they handled things differently, perhaps I should learn vim before using one its clones, edited to reflect neovim instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to yank to or put from a specific register, you have to prepend the name of the register with a `"`:

| Bad | Good |
| --- | --- |
| `+dd` | `"+dd` |
| `*dd` | `"*dd` |
| `+yy` | `"+yy` |
| `*yy` | `"*yy` |

Comment: Thank you, marked as the answer, perhaps I should be using vim before trying one of its clones!

Comment: Neovim is perfectly fine. You can keep using it all you want as long as you don't confuse the two: they share a lot of things but they have been steadily diverging for years so you shouldn't assume anything to work the same in both editors.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me in neovim under tmux on macOS:

init.vim (vimscript):

```
let g:clipboard = {
    \   'name': 'macos+tmux',
    \   'copy': {
    \      '+': ['pbcopy'],
    \      '*': ['tmux', 'load-buffer', '-'],
    \    },
    \   'paste': {
    \      '+': ['pbpaste'],
    \      '*': ['tmux', 'save-buffer', '-'],
    \   },
    \   'cache_enabled': 0,
    \ }
```

In neovim's source code, pbcopy/pbpaste is used without cache_enabled, and the documentation on that setting is confusing to me so I think it is safer to leave it off.

Note that you cannot only override one of the registers with this configuration -- meaning if you only want to change one of the registers' behavior, you still have to replicate the other register's functionality with this `g:clipboard` configuration. The source can be a helpful reference:

https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/22b538139606321bb1083665c510e81adb3d6670/runtime/autoload/provider/clipboard.vim

Also, since this isn't exactly documented, the idea with these configurations is that each array is a set of command line arguments, where the copied/pasted text is expected to be produced on STDIN and STDOUT respectively.